# change in config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion from V3.0 to V2.0 cannot revert

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services

I changed

```
config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3
```

from V3 to V2 to verify that JSON output is Verbose. However, when I change it back to V3, the output is still verbose, and I have to add

```
?$format=application/json;odata=verbose
```

in order to get JSON Light. Tips on how to get it back to the correct version?

Comment: If you set the MaxProtocolVersion to V3, then application/json should return you json light and application/json;odata=verbose should return old json format. Make sure you rebuild and restart the service after changing the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue use can extent a partial class

```
namespace Project.ServiceReference
{
public partial class MyEntities : global::System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext
{
    public TestDirectoryEntities(string uri)
        : base(new Uri(uri), DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3)
    {
        this.ResolveName = new global::System.Func<global::System.Type, string>   (this.ResolveNameFromType);
        this.ResolveType = new global::System.Func<string, global::System.Type>(this.ResolveTypeFromName);
        this.OnContextCreated();
    }
}
}
```